# App runs behind launch image

Tags: ios, image, jquery-mobile, cordova, launch

Sometimes when I run my iOS application, the app is opening up under the launch image, and the launch image doesn't seem to go away. I don't think I have any incorrect code because I do not have any code for the launch image. However, I am using local storage and maybe that has some impact on it?

Here is the image:

You can see at the bottom the blue part is the home page of the app. I am using jqm + phonegap...

[image]

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: 2.9.0, and also using cordova

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the plugin "CDVSplashScreen" from config.xml